Prove the Relationship Between Linear Independence and the Span Axiom
Let $V$ be a vector space with dim$(V) = n$, and let {$\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n$} be a set of vectors in $V$.
I would like to prove the following statements regarding the set {$\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n$}:

If the set is linearly independent, then it spans $V$.

If the set spans $V$, then it is linearly independent.


Could someone provide a proof or explanation for these statements? I tried:
1. If the set {$\alpha_1, α_2, ..., α_n$} is linearly independent, then it spans $V$.
Proof:
Assume that the set {$\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n$} is linearly independent and does not span V. In this case, there exists a vector $v$ in $V$ that cannot be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors in {$\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n$}.
Now, add this vector $ v $ to the set {$\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n$}. The new set of vectors will be {$\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n, v$}. This new set of vectors must be linearly independent. However, in an $n$-dimensional space (since dim$(V)=n$), it is impossible to have $n+1$ linearly independent vectors. This is a contradiction.
Therefore, our assumption is incorrect, and the set {$\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n$} must span $V$.
2. If the set {$α_1, α_2, ..., α_n$} spans $V$, then it is linearly independent.
Proof:
Assume that the set {$\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n$} spans $V$ but is not linearly independent. In this case, some vectors in this set can be expressed as linear combinations of the others.
Thus, we can select a subset of {$\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n$} that still spans $V$ but contains fewer than $n$ vectors. However, since the dimension of $V$ is $n$, we need at least $n$ linearly independent vectors to span $V$. This is a contradiction.
Therefore, our assumption is incorrect, and the set {$\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n$} must be linearly independent.
However it did not work. Also I do not want to use $n+1$ vector while proofing the theorem.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Why are you ending your proof with "However it did not work"?

I do not want to add a vector. I wanted to do it by using dimension theorems but I couldn't.

These proofs should be in any linear algebra textbook. If I recall right, the dimension theorems are proved from these facts, not the other way around.

These arguments depend on the way you have previously defined "dimension". That definition usually depends on arguments like yours. Please check your text and be sure you avoid circular reasoning.
